# MSCS in vSphere, HP EVA 4400 --> RDM, RAID, PRIVATE NETWORK

Tags: vmware-esx, cluster, vmware-vsphere

I'm in the move to set up an MS Cluster in vSphere and there's a few I havent yet understand.

```
* When I create my RDM disk in HP EVA they automatically get an RAID level, of course. But when I assign my RDM disk in vCenter to an storage (e.g. where my vm are, or another storage) what happends with the RAID? Will it be "double" RAID or how does it works? And what if it's different RAID between the RDM and the storage?


* When I read the document *"Setup for Failover Clustering and Microsoft Cluster Service" and other documents as well, its written that you must use private and public network adapters. How do I create private network adapters? And I guess the public network is my created Port Groups


* If im setting up an SQL 2008 cluster...do I then need a private network for every new cluster ip-adress??
```

Thanks in advance

//henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1 - the raid level is maintained, ESX has no software raid capabilities - the 'rdm/storage' part makes no sense.

Question 2 - public networks adapters are capable of being routed, private ones aren't (either they have no uplinks, are port groups assigned to use vlans that aren't being trunked, or are 10./192.168 networks).

Question 3 - each server needs its own regular public network that they VIP from plus they all need a heartbeat NIC that can be either routable or not - most people just go with a 10. address.

Terrible question by the way, try harder than just cut'n'pasting next time.